# How to use monte carlo method in matlab?

Tags: matlab, montecarlo, numerical-integration

I need to verify that pi = integral from 0 to 2 of(sqrt(4-x^2))dx using the monte carlo method and 10^7 random numbers. I am a little confused about how to implement this in matlab. Could someone help me out?

Comment: I'm attempting to do what you just posted right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integral describes a quarter of a circle. To calculate pi follow the steps:

1. Generate 10 ^ 7 points with coordinates (x, y) in [0 2] x [0 2]
2. Count the points with the property that x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 <= 4. Let `n` be their count.
3. Calculate the pi value: `pi = 4 * n / 10 ^ 7`

Comment: hmm I tried this, and all the points seem to end up inside the circle so the pi value ends up being 4. Maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: nevermind, I wasn't calculating the points in the right area. Let me try this again.